# can we store more than 65,535 characters in ms access database?

Tags: ms-access

I am saving a string to ms access data base, memo is the data type for the field. My string will have more than 65,535  characters but memo can save only 65,535  characters. Is there any data types/way to save more than 65,535  characters in ms access database ?

Comment: Ditch MsAccess. It's not a proper database.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's hardly helpful, sure enough a dedicated database server will be better suited to this, but slate of MS Access gets us nowhere.

Comment: msbyuva, out of curiosity what type of data are you storing and how many characters will it be?

Comment: @Matt -- text data, it will be more than 65,535 characters

Comment: @msbyuva What is the source of your data, e.g a text file? Is it essential to store the data within the database, could you not keep external files within the same directory and use as necessary?  Essentially the answer to your question is no, Access can't store more than that without manipulation, how is the data to be used within the database exactly?

Comment: @Mat.. basically its xml content and we want to save it in access. Our application will read from database and writes to database.

Comment: @msbyuva Ok, in that case I suggest you keep your XML text files in or around the database directory, and rather than load into tables, you reference the data directly. Check the references section for **XML** as it is supported and also look at the **TreeView** control to display the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the string in a txt file and a link to the file location in de Database. Of course you can not query the text from the database but the txt file itself can be queried by code in VBA.

Second option is to save the file as an OLE-object in database. Althow it isn't much different from above. You still can't query it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of storing as an OLE-object you also have the attachment field type now in the newer versions of Access